# Is there a way to use multiple CSS stylesheets in one masterpage?

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a web application and have written a CSS stylesheet to apply to all colour, layout, positioning etc. It's about 800 lines in all.

I want to provide the user with the option of selecting a colour scheme preference; at the moment this means I have 6 copies of the CSS file in my project, each with different colour attributes only (about 15 or 20 lines) to represent 6 different colour scheme options.

This seems like a lot of cumbersome duplication; all other CSS attributes remain the same in each copy.

Is there a way to separate the colour attributes into a separate CSS stylesheet to be applied with the general CSS stylesheet to the page?

Comment: You can include more than one stylesheet on a page...

Comment: Didn't know that; new to web development. Many thanks, this is exactly what I did..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to accomplish your goal is to extract every CSS-Element which is influenced by coloring and put it in one single selector like:

```
p, li, #whatever, .someClassInfluencedByColoring{
  color: #[yourColor];
}
```

you could put this declaration into one CSS-File (for example color.css) and then use import statements like the following in a master CSS-File:

```
@import url("color.css");
```

Another way would be to use [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) or [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) and use variables where you define your color once in every stylesheet.

Answer (score 1):

Make color style sheets. Lets say your main has a class called

```
Main.css

.example{
float:right;
width:100px;
height:auto;
}
```

And you want the color applied to it with a user specified color scheme.

Make the smaller color schemes like so

```
Color1.css

.example{
color:orange;
}

Color2.css

.example{
color:red;
}
```

In the main index page would look like this:

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css" />

    <?php
    //user get color scheme from db query
    $color = //user color variable
    if($color == 1){
    echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="color1.css" />';
    }elseif($color == 2){
    echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="color2.css" />';
    }
    ?>
</head>
```

That's the only way I can think of.

Answer (score -1):

just use

```
var bleh = $('body');
function changeToBlue() {
    bleh.css("background","blue");
}
```